# I want to know in which cardinal direction are my nearby locations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a project in which I have to show nearby hotels within 10 kms of the current position of the user. I am successfully getting the result by the below given sql query. Further if the user selects north/south/west/east direction then I have to show user only nearby hotels available in that particular direction. What can I do to know in which direction the nearby hotels are in?

```
$nearby = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * ,((((acos(sin((?*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude*pi()/180))+cos((?*pi()/180)) * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((?- longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)) as distance FROM hotel_data HAVING distance<= 10 ORDER BY distance") )->setBindings([$request->latitude,$request->latitude,$request->longitude]);`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [dougv.com](https://www.dougv.com/2009/07/calculating-the-bearing-and-compass-rose-direction-between-two-latitude-longitude-coordinates-in-php/) You want to use this function to get an accurate bearing that also keeps in mind the curvature of the earth.

```
function getRhumbLineBearing($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
   //difference in longitudinal coordinates
   $dLon = deg2rad($lon2) - deg2rad($lon1);

   //difference in the phi of latitudinal coordinates
   $dPhi = log(tan(deg2rad($lat2) / 2 + pi() / 4) / tan(deg2rad($lat1) / 2 + pi() / 4));

   //we need to recalculate $dLon if it is greater than pi
   if(abs($dLon) > pi()) {
      if($dLon > 0) {
         $dLon = (2 * pi() - $dLon) * -1;
      }
      else {
         $dLon = 2 * pi() + $dLon;
      }
   }
   //return the angle, normalized
   return (rad2deg(atan2($dLon, $dPhi)) + 360) % 360;
}
```

Then to turn it into a compass direction you can use this function, also on that same site:

```
function getCompassDirection($bearing) {
   $tmp = round($bearing / 22.5);
   switch($tmp) {
      case 1:
         $direction = "NNE";
         break;
      case 2:
         $direction = "NE";
         break;
      case 3:
         $direction = "ENE";
         break;
      case 4:
         $direction = "E";
         break;
      case 5:
         $direction = "ESE";
         break;
      case 6:
         $direction = "SE";
         break;
      case 7:
         $direction = "SSE";
         break;
      case 8:
         $direction = "S";
         break;
      case 9:
         $direction = "SSW";
         break;
      case 10:
         $direction = "SW";
         break;
      case 11:
         $direction = "WSW";
         break;
      case 12:
         $direction = "W";
         break;
      case 13:
         $direction = "WNW";
         break;
      case 14:
         $direction = "NW";
         break;
      case 15:
         $direction = "NNW";
         break;
      default:
         $direction = "N";
   }
   return $direction;
}
```

Then when you've appointed a compass rose direction to all coordinates you can filter them easely.

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * ....."));

/** get the direction as a compass direction **/
$user_direction = $request->direction;// N

/** group general directions togeter from a simple north, south, east west **/
$filter= [
       'N' => ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'NW', 'NNW'],
       'E' => ['E','ESE','ENE','NE', 'SE'], 
       'W' => ['S','SSW','SW','SE','SSE'],
       'S' => ['W','WSW','WNW','SW', 'NW'],
    ];
/** get any direction  that appears in this array ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'NW', 'NNW'] **/
$filter_direction = $filter[$user_direction];

/** The filtered locations are here in the $filtered variable **/
$filtered = $results->filter(function($item, $key) use ($filter_direction ) {
    $bearing = getRhumbLineBearing($request->latitude, 
                                   $request->longitude, 
                                   $result->latitude, 
                                   $result->longitude);
    $compass = getCompassDirection($bearing);
    return in_array($compass);

})->all();
```

Comment: I read the documentation on dougv.com you gave above in your answer and it helped me get my work done. Thank you so much for the help :)